# What is the word/phrase for killing someone for their color or race?

Tags: word-request

What is the word/phrase for killing someone for their color or race?
Like: “George Floyd’s murder is called  ________(the word/phrase here).”

Comment: *En masse*, it's called ***ethnic cleansing***. But that's not really appropriate for a single instance of (race-hate / xenophobia motivated) manslaughter / murder.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for **[hate crime](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hate-crime)**?

> a crime or crimes, usually involving violence, committed against someone because of their race or religion, because they are gay, etc.

---

There is also the word **[lynch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynching)** (as a verb "to lynch (someone)" or as a noun "a lynching"), but this is more specialized and is probably not a good fit for the murder of George Floyd:

> Lynching is a premeditated extrajudicial killing by a group. It is most often used to characterize informal public executions by a mob in order to punish an alleged transgressor, punish a convicted transgressor, or intimidate.

Answer (score 1):

Racially motivated murder, since you only asked for killing because of colour or race. “Hate crime” would be more general for the reason, and crime obviously covers less serious crime.